# Expand/collapse, update icon class

Tags: jquery

I am trying to write a simple function where I click a div and a hidden area expands and on another click it collapses. That part works. But in addition, I'd like to show an arrow indicator change to Up when expanded and Down when collapsed. That part seems to work only on initial click, when it expands but does not change back when the area collapses. What am I missing?

Here's what I've written

```
$(".myDiv").click(function() {
        var $expandable = $(this).parent().find(".expandable");
        $expandable.slideToggle("fast");
        if ($expandable.is(":visible")) {
            $(this).find("span").removeClass("Down").addClass("Up");
        } else {
            $(this).find("span").removeClass("Up").addClass("Down");
        }
});
```

Comment: Can you give the html snippet you are working with ?

Comment: You need to show us your markup as well.

Comment: What is your html? It seems you are close, but it seems to be a selector issue or possible scope with the use of ``$(this)`` in your ``if`` statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than test on visibility, test for the class?

```
$(".myDiv").click(function() {
        var $expandable = $(this).parent().find(".expandable");
        $expandable.slideToggle("fast");
        var $span = $(this).find("span");
        if ($span.hasClass("Down") ){
            $span.removeClass("Down").addClass("Up");
        } else {
            $span.removeClass("Up").addClass("Down");
        }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It is always a good option to use class for comparison. However if you want to use visibility for displaying your arrow then you will need to check the visibility before you toggle the expandable element as the toggle method adds a delay so when your browser executes the comparison line, the visibility of the element has already changed.

```
$(".myDiv").click(function() {
    var $expandable = $(this).parent().find(".expandable");

if ($expandable.css("display") == "none") {
        $(this).find("span").removeClass("Up").addClass("Down");
    } else {
        $(this).find("span").removeClass("Down").addClass("Up");
    }        
    $expandable.slideToggle("fast");
   });
```

This seemed to do the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

Change position of slideToggle and test for visible. It will always be visible the way you have it. As soon as you start the slide when it is closed, it becomes "visible"